# Bootstrap Popover when hovering over an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am creating a notification window for which i am using bootstrap alert class and i have trimmed the string but i want to show the entire notification as popover when user hovers over them. This is the code i am using to display notification

```
<div class="alert alert-success fade in">
<a style="padding: 0px" href="#" class="close"                                                          data-dismiss="alert"                        onclick="makeArchive(${notifications.notificationId})">&times;</a>
<strong style="cursor: pointer;" data-container="body"
data-toggle="usersMobile" data-placement="right"
data-trigger="hover" data-animation="true"
onmouseover="showPopover(${notifications.notificationText})"
data-content="${notifications.notificationText}"
onclick="openModal(${notifications.notificationId})">
<c:out value="${notifications.trimmedString}"></c:out>
</strong>
```

On Mouseover i call the function popOver

```
function popOver(notificationId){

    $('[data-toggle="'+notificationId+'"]').popover("show");

}
```

But the popover is not Showing

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before displaying the popover you need to initialize the popover. Following link is a fiddle for your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/1tLof1ph/12/

```
$('[data-toggle="usersMobile"]').popover({html : true});
```

-Thanks